# Como eu posso baralhar um vetor com estruturas? C

Tags: c, array, random

Preciso de baralhar peças de domino numa função, e não estou a conseguir fazer.

```
void baralhar(int domino[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=1;i<=29;i++)
    {
        int r = rand() % 28;

        int aux = domino[i];
        domino[i] = domino[r];
        domino[r] = aux;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem certeza que está usando C? Essa estrutura de declarar variável dentro do for, que eu me lembre não era possível em C.

Comment: Pode esclarecer o que não está dando certo?

Comment: Este é o output que eu recebo se correr o meu programa:[0:0] [0:1] [0:2] [0:3] [0:4] [0:5] [0:6] [1:1] [1:2] [1:3] [1:4] [1:5] [1:6] [2:2] [2:3] [2:4] [2:5] [2:6] [3:3] [3:4] [3:5] [3:6] [4:4] [4:5] [4:6] [5:5] [5:6] [6:6] [0:5] [5:0] [4:1] [0:1] [0:1] [0:3] [1:1] [1:1] [1996321010:0] [6:2] [6:3] [2:4] [2:0] [1:0] [2:3] [2:4] [2:5] [2:6] [3:3] [3:4] [3:5] [3:6] [4:4] [4:5] [4:6] [5:5] [5:6] [6:6] e devia receber os primeiros 28 numeros por ordem e os segundos 28 numeros deveriam ser numeros random contudo aparece um numeros estranho no meio dos segundos numeros e eu não sei o que é.

Comment: O tamanho do seu vetor "dominio" é 28? Se for, seu for não pode ir até 29. Ele deveria ir de 0 a 27. Ou seja, for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++). Se for o caso, me avise, publicarei uma resposta explicando melhor o porquê desses "números estranhos".